# Class Library with all Models not getting Xml Comments for Swagger

Tags: nuget, swagger, swashbuckle, xml-comments, nuspec

I have a common class library that is packaged as it's own nugget library.

it's nuspec looks like the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
    <id>MyCompany.MyDTOPackage</id>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <authors>Nate Tregillus</authors>
    <owners>nate</owners>
    <projectUrl>https://github.com/myCompany/ClassLibrary</projectUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <releaseNotes>Intital Release</releaseNotes>
    <description>Common Data Transfer Objects for all apps</description>
    <tags>dto models</tags>
    </metadata>
</package>
```

When I compile a nuget package from this file, the contents are the following:

```
lib
-- net45
-- -- MyCompany.MyDTOPackage.dll
-- -- MyCompany.MyDTOPackage.xml
```

When I attempt to use this package, and utilize the models in the package in my swagger documentation, they appear when I localy debug, but not when I deploy my webapi project via Kudu. looking at the package Kudu is building, it explicitly ignores the `MyCompany.MyDTOPackage.xml` file entirely. I do not understand why. is there something I can do to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a nugget, swagger or swashbuckle issue, the fact that it works locally it points to a problem in the deployment...

I will recommend you to contact the Kudu team:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu#questions

An alternative will be to include the XML file as an **embedded resource** and load it that way. 
If you are using [Swashbuckle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle/) you will need to add an xml include like:

```
IncludeXmlComments(() => new XPathDocument(
        thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("FilePath.xml")));
```

If you are using [Swagger-Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swagger-Net/) it should work, check that you have `IncludeAllXmlComments`, it is enabled by default.

[image]

Comment: oh interesting! I this looks like it might work for me! trying it out now.

Comment: Yes, it should work, I'm the developer of Swagger-Net and I have make XML comments a top priority, tested all possible scenarios, there should not be any problems

Comment: i am not sure how you are compiling your comments at the root of the project... what does your xml documentation settings look like in the project's build settings?

Comment: I ask because I attempted to use these properties, but when I gave the project to Kudu via github, it failed to find the file...

Comment: The key here is ***embedded resource*** that is no longer a file that you need to "give" to anyone or find, it gets embedded into your dll.

Comment: If you want to make sure you don't miss anything use the ***IncludeAllXmlComments*** you can see the code here: https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net/blob/master/Swagger.Net/Application/SwaggerDocsConfig.cs#L248

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151446/discussion-between-heldersepu-and-nathan-tregillus).